# Transit at Schiphol from the UK as an EU citizen, Covid rules

Tags: transit, covid-19, netherlands, ams

I am having trouble finding and understanding the Covid-rules regarding transiting at Schiphol. The relevant details would be:

- Travel is from Wales (UK) to Germany
- Traveller is a German citizen and UK resident
- Traveller had their second shot over 14 days prior to travel
- Evidence for the vaccination will be the vaccination letter issues by the NHS in Wales

Under these circumstances, is transiting in Schiphol permitted? Are there additional demands, ie a recent negative test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Under these circumstances, is transiting in Schiphol permitted?

Yes.

> Are there additional demands, ie a recent negative test?

Strictly speaking you also need to fill in the 'traveller public health declaration' which [may be downloaded here](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/documents/publications/2020/07/07/information-for-passengers-flying-to-and-from-the-netherlands). As I explained in a comment, I have not been asked for those forms in AMS (both on arrival or departure). Nevertheless, it may be something that the airline could check when you're checking in (as it's also listed in Timatic).

I also recommend looking at the German entry requirements as well. Also note that the Netherlands is currently marked [red on the ECDC map](https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/covid-19/situation-updates/weekly-maps-coordinated-restriction-free-movement).

The Netherlands has [an exception to the mandatory negative test result requirement when changing planes](https://www.government.nl/topics/c/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/mandatory-negative-test-results-and-declaration/rules-when-changing-planes):

> **Transit/transfer in the Netherlands**
>
> **If you start your journey in a high-risk area or country and change planes in the Netherlands**
>
> - You do not need to show a negative NAAT (PCR) test result or rapid test result on arrival in the Netherlands.
> - A transfer is when you change planes and continue your journey within a few hours, and in any case within 1 day without leaving the airport where you transfer.

It's not entirely clear from the English translation that this applies to travel originating from the UK. [The Dutch version](https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/coronavirus-covid-19/nederland-inreizen/testbewijs-voor-inreizen-nederland/regels-bij-overstappen) of the same page describes the same rules using the qualifier *an area with an orange travel advisory*. At this moment, [the UK does have an orange travel advisory](https://www.nederlandwereldwijd.nl/landen/verenigd-koninkrijk/reizen/reisadvies).

Comment: I think they would also need [the health declaration](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/documents/publications/2020/07/07/information-for-passengers-flying-to-and-from-the-netherlands), right?

Comment: @jdouglas strictly speaking, probably yes. Personally I've got these forms both at the point of checking in on another flight (with final destination AMS but with a layover elsewhere) and on the second flight prior to landing in AMS. Upon arrival in AMS I wasn't asked for that declaration (both on arrival and departure). Nevertheless, I'll edit it in. :)